# What is the meaning and use of modules.ts file generated when creating ionic page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 and i created ionic page using (`$ ionic g page page1`)this command 
it generate following files
 (1) `page1.html` 
 (2) `page1.scss` 
 (3) `page1.ts` 
 (4) `page1.module.ts`
I want know what is important of this `page1.module.ts` file how it is using?

Comment: It is for lazy loading of pages https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vGokwMXPQItZmTHZQbTO4qwj_SQymFhRS_nJmiH0K3w/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `2 CLIs` for generating pages.

```
ionic generate page Login --no-module

ionic generate page Login
```

If you use `--no-module` option then it won't generate `page module`.We need page module for implementing `lazy loading` pattern. If you don't like to use `lazy loading` then you don't need to create it. But `lazy loading` will give a huge performance boost to your app.

*Why do we need `page1.module.ts` :*

On `lazy loading` pattern where you can `import` the `components`, `pipes`, `directives` or any other `module` which is related to that page.So you don't need to `import` it into the main module (i.e. `app.module.ts`). Hence it'll give a huge performance boost to the entire app.

Here is an official blog post about [**lazy loading**](http://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/).